# How do you bind a kendo dropdownlist to a model property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a kendo dropdownlist defined in my view as follows:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("RowCategoryID")
                .OptionLabel("Select Row Category...")
                .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.RowCategories.Select(r => new { Key = r.Key, Value = r.Value }), "Key", "Value"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
```

My model has a `Dictionary<int,string>` called `RowCategories` which has the key/value pairs for the DDL. It also has an `int` property called `RowCategoryID` representing the current `RowCategory` selected out of the `RowCategories` list.

The DDL populates with the values from `RowCategories` but it will not select the option with the value of `RowCategoryID`. It just defaults to "Select Row Category...".

How do I get it to select the option with the value of `RowCategoryID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the method `Value()`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("RowCategoryID")
            .OptionLabel("Select Row Category...")
            .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.RowCategories.Select(r => new { Key = r.Key, Value = r.Value }), "Key", "Value"))
            .Value(Model.RowCategoryID) // <- this
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
```

Although I could not find that method in [the documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DropDownListBuilder), I have spotted it the [demos](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-.mvc/dropdownlist)(see "Basic usage").

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. I'm noticing a pattern though. `.Value` requires a `string` and `RowCategoryID` is an `int`. Any Dictionary<int,string> types don't bind properly, but Dictionary<string,string> does. Wonder if there's a connection.

Comment: @Legion well, then try to cast it `Value(Model.RowCategoryID.ToString())`. Did you tried that ? Also, your dont need to change your your dictionary, just do `Key = r.Key.ToString()`

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out it's unrelated to kendo. RowCategoryID was being populated on the server side, but was being lost in javascript, leaving the control nothing to bind with.

Comment: @Legion nice to hear!